# Is there any application for checking 'what's loading onto the website right now' kindof?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I am developing a website and sometimes the browsers keeps loading, and I would like to know exactly what's making it load for so long. It gets stuck kindof.

So I wonder if there is any application or way to check what is getting loaded onto the page, so I can see what element or object it gets stuck on?

The website uses php/javascript/mysql and html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) allows you to see that other than other great options

Answer (score 6):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a nice add-on for Firefox. It will tell you that, and much more

Answer (score 5):

Firefox + [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843). In the net tab you can see which resources are loading.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Fiddler for this type of thing. You can view a timeline of all elements loading on the page.

http://www.fiddlertool.com/

Answer (score 1):

Besides Firebug/Firefox, also look into the Developer tools in Chrome. The latest addition is the Chrome Speed Tracer extension, which lets you see exactly what loads are taking how much time, and all kinds of other stuff.